# Better layout of Expose on Leopard

Tags: macos, expose

Is it possible for Expose on Mac OS X Leopard to arrange the preview windows in a more optimal manner? After a while on superuser, opening up a new windows for each question that interests me, Expose looks like this:

[image]

It is of minimal value seeing each preview is so small. I have no hope in hell seeing the contents of each windows.

Is there some secret setting or 3rd party application that could fix this for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a bit of a bug due to the algorithm in Expose that has to do with the height and placement of windows. If all the windows on screen are the same size and at the same relative position (eg. not cascaded, all on top of each other, or at the same y position on the screen) they will arrange themselves side by side. The workaround is to try and make sure your windows have slightly differing relative positions (in terms of y position on the screen) or ensure you have another window visible that has a slightly different size.

I can confirm that Expose in Snow Leopard fixes this "bug" has been there since 10.3 when Expose was first introduced.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found works is opening an application even if you don't use it. If all you have are lots of Safari windows open, Expose will arrange them in a single horizontal line... very annoying and pointless when they're so small you can't see the one you want. I like opening Stickies because the sticky notes can be made very small and they're colored so you won't confuse them with something else. Expose will then arrange all the windows in no particular order all over your screen... much bigger and easier to see. Stickies are also great for copying useful information that you come across and don't want to forget. You can close Stickies and all your notes are still there when you open the app again. And... I just tried this, Chealion is correct about the windows being aligned in a straight line because they are the same size. I opened ten Safari windows and when I made just one window a different size, Expose arranged all of them randomly over the screen.